# KFold Cross Validation for KNN Text Classifier in R

Tags: r, validation, knn, text-classification

I have created a text classifier which classifies comments into various categories such as

```
      Comment                          Category 
Good Service provided                   Service
Excellent Communication                 Communication
```

I have done classification using:

```
 knn(modeldata[train, ], modeldata[test,] , cl[train], k =2, use.all = TRUE)
```

Now i want to evaluate this model using K-Fold Cross Validation. I am expecting a number which i can use to know if model is overfitting or underfitting etc

I have used

```
knn.cv(modeldata[train, ], cl[train], k =2, use.all = TRUE)
```

But help of this command says it will return NA if model is confused. Please guide

Answer (score 1):

Which package are you using for knn? you can use caret for CV like the following (example with the iris dataset):

```
training <- iris
ctrl <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv",repeats = 3)  
knnFit <- train(Species ~ ., data = training, method = "knn", 
                trControl = ctrl, preProcess = c("center","scale"))
knnFit
```

with the output

```
k-Nearest Neighbors 

150 samples
  4 predictor
  3 classes: 'setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica' 

Pre-processing: centered (4), scaled (4) 
Resampling: Cross-Validated (10 fold, repeated 3 times) 
Summary of sample sizes: 135, 135, 135, 135, 135, 135, ... 
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  k  Accuracy   Kappa    
  5  0.9511111  0.9266667
  7  0.9577778  0.9366667
  9  0.9533333  0.9300000

Accuracy was used to select the optimal model using  the largest value.
The final value used for the model was k = 7.
```

Comment: I am using "Class" package for KNN. I am not sure if it because of number of columns in iris dataset, aforementioned code is working for iris dataset but not for my dataset (which has only two columns). When I run above command, i get below message:                                                                                                   Warning in preProcess.default(thresh = 0.95, k = 5, method = c("center",  :
  These variables have zero variances:

Comment: I have also tried below statements but getting error message:                                                                   .               knnFit1 <- train(Category ~ Text, data = x,
                 method = "knn",
                 preProcess = NULL,
                 trControl = trainControl(method = "cv", number=5,                                .                classProbs = FALSE))                                                              . Error Message: One or more factor levels in the outcome has no data.  Looked at all factors but did not find any blank/empty level